# Transform a DataFrame with its columns

Tags: python, dataframe

I have no idea how to title this action. Please let me explain. I have the following DataFrame.

```
                      4046          4225        4770
region                                              
SouthCentral  1.691640e+08  5.869317e+07  2412798.40
California    1.149494e+08  1.051475e+08  7710648.67
West          1.192689e+08  7.687167e+07  5973364.45
Northeast     1.453107e+07  1.421793e+08  1780119.33
Southeast     1.059120e+08  2.750374e+07   357360.93
```

I am going to convert it into

```
region           type       value                                     
SouthCentral     4046      1.691640e+08    
SouthCentral     4225      5.869317e+07
SouthCentral     4770      2412798.40
...
```

Using `transform` looks unable to solve the above issue, in the worse case I can write a loop to transform it but I am wondering if there is a nicer way for it.

Comment: The key vocabulary is "wide" and "long" if you want to search for this or the inverse transformation

Comment: @roganjosh yes, thank you, I have my answer in `Reshape wide to long in pandas`